# Is the "__half" a native C++ type?

Tags: c++

I am looking at https://github.com/NVIDIA/CUDALibrarySamples/blob/master/cuSPARSELt/spmma/spmma_example.cpp#L115-L117, and I see the `__half` type, which I believe corresponds to half precision float. I am wondering if this is a native C++ type? If not, is there a native float16 type?

Comment: I belive `__half` is a compiler extension.  There is no standard `float16` type.  I'm aware of a few different implementations of a 16-bit float in C++, but they're non-standard (as in:  not part of the C++ standard).

Comment: Things starting with `__` are reserved for the compiler; they wouldn't generally be standardized (with some exceptions, such as `__cplusplus`)

Comment: @ChrisMM -- you're right for this case, but the actual rule is that names that **contain** two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. I don't think anybody does anything other than two leading underscores; the internal ones are a cfront artifact.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Indeed, although note that in C the rule is only two leading underscores. One for the pub quiz, and not really for you either - I'm sure you're aware of that given your day job.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @Bathsheba -- good clarification.

Answer (score 3):

While there is a IEEE-754 definition of 16-bit floating point, there's no C++ portable type for it as of yet. GGC uses `_Float16`, CUDA uses `__half`, etc.

There are also some 16-bit floating point variants like [bfloat16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format).

> For [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath), I currently define a `using HALF = uint16_t;` which is not as type-safe as I'd like.

Comment: yeah this is a CUDA codebase that I saw this in. Do you know if `__half` is equivalent to float16 or bfloat16? I'm having a hard time googling documentation for `__half`

Comment: Based on [this page](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html), ``__half`` is the [IEEE 754 float16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). There's a distinct type for bfloat16 which makes sense because it's for a [special use case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 2):

Confusingly, __half is not, but what you probably mean by half (fp16) is.

Essentially, __half is not a native type, nor is it in a sense a reserved keyword (beyond the standard nature of `__` being reserved for compiler vendor implementations).

What you're referring to as "half" is a colloquial term for the IEEE-754:2008 Binary16 type (otherwise known as FP16) which is codified as a new addition into both the C and C++ 23 specifications.

Because of the nature of C++, you will be able to access the type via its C naming convention of _Float16, or its C++ naming convention of std::float16_t

On the topic of "Half". The naming comes from IEEE 32 bit floating points being regularly known as "single" precision, and their 64 bit siblings being known as "doubles". Invert the nomenclature and you have "half" precision types.

For details you can "C" the specifications here:

C23: https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3054.pdf (see page 562)

IEEE-754:2008 (or newer): https://irem.univ-reunion.fr/IMG/pdf/ieee-754-2008.pdf

In usage: Work in progress for GCC implementation of Complex "Half": https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106652

Depending on how up to date your compiler is, you may already have support for the type. From my own testing (and current work) _Float16 is available in Clang-14, GCC-12, ICC 2021.2 and ICX 2021.2.

Fortran has had the type since 2018

Comment: What about C++ before C++23?

Comment: @einpoklum
Some vendor implementations may have chosen to support the type (see __half in cuda) but these were nonstandard and not backed up/mandated by the specification.

That's not a good/bad thing. In terms of hardware support, it's also case dependent. x86 (intel/AMD) mostly support the f16c ISA extension, and sapphire rapids support the type natively.

As for ARM, IIRC FP16 support was mandated as part of the ARM v8.5 extension.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a native C++ type. C++ only supports `float` (typically IEEE 754 binary32), `double` (typically binary64) and `long double` (variable width by implementation, but at least as large as `double`). CUDA supports a half-precision `float` because GPUs support it, and the GPUs support it because it's not uncommon for GPUs to need to do a lot of low precision floating point computations, and you can do a *lot* of those operations with half-precision floats, but there is no syntax that allows you to request them in standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

C++ requires `float` and `double`, which are single and double precision floating point types. The exact nature of these is down to the implementation. IEEE754 is common, but by no means ubiquitous.

C++ is not required to implement a half precision type. Your compiler might support one. Else you could search for a library that implements one, along with a good suite of mathematical functions.